# Hadoop MapReduce does not process/ output is wrong?

Tags: java, string, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I'm stuck with `Hadoop` giving me weird output or not processing the `MapReduce` at all. Even if it succeeded the output is wrong, and to me it seems like the code is right. What I am trying to do is `parse` and `count` the `length of a string` which I would like to parse every `4 ";"` symbols as the data is joined together (like `customerID;date;jobdescription;associations etc etc` just one big string).

That's my code:

**Mapper:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
public class TwitterMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, IntWritable, IntWritable> { 

    //private final IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
   // private Text  = new Text();
    private final IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private final IntWritable length = new IntWritable();


    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) 
                     throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      // Format per tweet is id;date;hashtags;tweet;
      String dump = value.toString();
      int startIndex = 1;
      if(StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf(dump, ";", 4) > -1){
          startIndex = StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf(dump,";",3) + 1;
          String tweet = dump.substring(startIndex,dump.lastIndexOf(';'));

          //data.set(tweet.length());
          one.set(tweet.length());
          context.write(one,length);
          //context.write(dump,length);
          //length.set(); 
      }
   }
}
```

**Reducer:**

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

public class TwitterReducer extends Reducer<IntWritable, IntWritable, IntWritable, IntWritable> {

    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

    public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
              throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        int sum = 0;
        for (IntWritable value : values) {
            sum = sum + value.get();
        }
               result.set(sum);

        context.write(key, result);
    }
}
```

Output that I get looks like this:

4   0
7   0
7   0
7   0
7   0
7   0
7   0
7   0
7   0
7   0
7   0
7   0
7   0
7   0
7   0
7   0
7   0
7   0
7   0
7   0

while the output I would be expecting is the number of characters for every 4 sections of the string (for every customer), something quite variable as the output is just the same. 
So like this:
1 20192
2 19292
3 23890

etc.

Comment: First of all, share ur driver too. Next show what's the current output and the expected one.

Comment: I am unsure what do you want me to share to be honest, and I showed the output and expected one just now. Thanks a lot

Comment: I just wanted to check which `InputFormat` u r using. Driver is  the method where job setup & submission is done. @Alexey has  diagnosed the issue well, you should accept it. In `eclipse`, the best way to override a method is to do a `ctrl+o` inside a class body, and look for methods u want to implement. It restricts user from using a incorrect signature for a method. In other IDEs, similar command will be available.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you have incorrectly override `map` and `reduce` methods. Correct signatures of these methods are:

```
public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException

public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
```

Due to improper override your methods (`map`, `reduce`) don't even get called.

I also found some other mistakes:

- in `map` method you didn't set `length` before `context.write`, so values in your mapper's output is zero for every input.
- your reducer should extends `Reducer<IntWritable, IntWritable, IntWritable, IntWritable>` if you want to write pairs of `IntWritable` to the output.

What your program is doing now:

1. Transforms input line `"customerID;date;jobdescription;associations;"` into a pair of `"associations".length()` and `0`.
2. Sums all zero values at the reducer and writes a pair of `"associations".length()` and `0` to the output.

Comment: I changed the signatures but the output is still wrong (look at updated post). Sadly then the context write has an error if I do that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: See my improved answer.

Comment: Changed, any idea how to make the transformation into "customerID;date;jobdescription;associations;".length()? Thanks a lot.